# Silverlight Out of browser displays white screen

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, silverlight

I have a **silverlight application** which runs in **out of browser** mode. While opening the application sometimes it lunches the **blank screen** which is stopping us to proceed further, once this happens none of the silverlight application "out of browser" launches and other SL applications is also showing blank screen. Once we re-install the silverlight in the client machine, the application starts working. and we have set the silverlight settings not to take any latest update, but this problem occurs very frequently.

Though reinstalling the silverlight will solve the problem but it don't look like right way to over come from this problem. moreover, we cannot go to each client machine to do the same.

Please provide a right solution to over come from this problem, if you have come across.

**Note: We are facing this problem more frequently starting from last week**

Answer (score 1):

In our case, the root cause turned out to be a "bug" in System Center Configuration Manager that was periodically setting AllowLaunchOfElevatedTrustApps to 0.

`HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Silverlight\AllowLaunchOfElevatedTrustApps`

`HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Silverlight\AllowLaunchOfElevatedTrustApps`

Check the values of these registry keys when the problem is occurring. (Reinstalling Silverlight resets these values.)

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled upon this issue a couple days ago. In our case, it turned out to be an unsupported version of font (yes, quite bizarre) that was installed along with MS Office upgrade.

**Steps to fix Silverlight White Screen Of Death**

1. Open registry editor (Regedit.exe) in admin/privileged account
2. In registry goto the following node : `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts`
3. Check if the font `ARIALUNI.TTF` is available in Data column.
4. Delete the entry containing `ARIALUNI.TTF`.
5. Close the registry and Browse the Silverlight application from a new instance of IE

Pro tip - take backup of the registry content in case it doesn't work out for you.